# Mounted drive does not show up on Disk Utility, Desktop, Finder Sidebar

Tags: macos, disk-utility, diskutil

I've an external drive that consists of 2 partitions, one NTFS that I use for storing stuff and one Journaled that I use for TimeMachine.

I've connected the drive to my Mac but now the NTFS partition is not showing up on the desktop, finder sidebar or disk util app, while the TimeMachine partition does.

I though that the NTFS partition wasn't being mounted but if I go to /Volumes it's there and I can in fact browse the drive, open the stuff that's saved there and also save new stuff, so the drive is working fine, it's just not showing up where it should..

It even works and shows up on the Terminal when executing the `diskutil list` command, and I can `diskutil unmount disk3s2` and `diskutil mount disk3s2` without issues.

What do I need to do for the partition to show on the aforementioned places?

Answer (score 2):

A simple restart fixed the issue for some reason.

Comment: Please mark your post as answered.